# Change Fabric and Crashlytics pods with a Firebase/Crashlytics to Upload missing required dSYMs

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, crash-reports

I want to upload missing required dSYMs to firebase console but i can't because Firebase Crashlytics are update [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4qCh.png), So i change Fabric to Firebase/Crashlytics in my code.

In appDelegate

`import FirebaseCrashlytics
        FirebaseApp.configure()`

In Build Phases [Run Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e74PG.png)

And i run this command in terminal

```
/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs
```

And i got this after run command [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4qCh.png)

Still not fixed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKkQS.png)

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give proper path as below

```
${PODS_ROOT}/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}
```

Comment: Dear Rajan can you give me a sample because i don't know how to used for example i don't know hot to get path of upload-symbols and project-dir of googleService-Info and DWARF)_DSYM path, please help me.

Comment: Just put this path I have given in run script section of build phase in Xcode.

Comment: Dear Rajan i copied this path to run script but i get an error Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code.

Comment: Solve it,  via terminal by this path /path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs, i get the path of upload-symbols and GoogleService-Info.plist in my project folder and DSYM i get from itunesconnect and i downloaded the folder of dSYMs and then i copied the path of UUID that are missing in firebase console and then run it in terminal and uploaded. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Below I posted what my code looks like for a successful call to the upload symbols script. I suggest going through [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports-new-sdk?platform=ios&authuser=0) again to figure out where you may have gone wrong.

find /Users/okodysh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ftqksfkpdvisbtaozpqzzjiizpfk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -name "myApp.app.dSYM" | xargs -I {} $PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /Users/okodysh/Desktop/iOSApps/myApp/myApp/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios {}

Answer (score 0):

After ours of struggling with this problem finally solved it using this approach:

use this command in Terminal: `/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs`

Important thing is instead of `/path/to/pods/directory` you should enter the path to your pods folder in your application folder, and instead of `/path/to` you should enter the path to the GoogleService-Info.plist which it's in your project folder too. And the last one is, instead of `/path/to/dSYMs` you should enter the path to your archive which is with the format of .xcarchive.

For finding the .xcarchive path, you shoud first archived your application then go to Organizer of Xcode and select your build then right click on it and select `Show in finder` and then right click on your .xcarchive file and select `Show package contents`. This is it, you can copy this path and paste it instead of `/path/to/dSYMs` and then hit enter to start uploading to Firebase crashlytics.